# Swift: UIView appear in UITableView cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

Im having an issue putting a UIView that I created in a specific UITableView cell. Here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

//MARK : Properties
var tableView = UITableView()
var items: [String] = ["Age", "Gender", "Smoking Hx", "Occup. -Ag", "Family Hx", "Chronic Lung Disease Radiology", "Chronic Lung Disease Hx", "Nodule Border", "Nodule Location", "Satellite Lesions", "Nodule Pattern Cavity", "Nodule Size"]
var navigationBar = NavigationBar()
var gender = GenderView()
var maleIcon = MaleIconView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Create TableView
    tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.bounds.height * 0.097, self.view.bounds.width,
        self.view.bounds.height - self.view.bounds.height * 0.097);
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
    self.view.addSubview(tableView)



    //Create Navigation Bar with custom class
    self.navigationBar = NavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: self.view.bounds.height * 0.097))
    self.view.addSubview(navigationBar)

}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}




func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.items.count
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell")! as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = self.items[indexPath.row]

    //Cell wont turn grey when selected
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None

    //Want to add UIView male Icon in first row
    if(indexPath.row == 0){
        maleIcon = MaleIconView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 55, height: 55))
        maleIcon.center.x = cell.center.x + cell.center.x * 0.5
        maleIcon.center.y = cell.contentView.center.y
        maleIcon.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * maleIcon.bounds.size.width
        //maleIcon.layer.borderWidth = 3.0
        cell.addSubview(maleIcon)
    }


    return cell

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

 return self.view.bounds.height * 0.15

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.row)!")

}
}
```

Maybe the issue exists within the MaleIconView()? Here is the code to that:

```
class MaleIconView: UIView {

var maleView = UIView()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.frame = frame
    setUpView()
}

func setUpView(){

    maleView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.width, self.bounds.height)
    maleView.alpha = 1
    maleView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    maleView.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * maleView.bounds.size.width
    self.addSubview(maleView)

}



func hide(){
    self.removeFromSuperview()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

}
```

Im trying to get the UIView to appear on the right side of the cell 0. There is also this issue where the indexPath's are all off, i think this could be of some issue to why the UIView appears in multiple cells. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try cell.contentView.addSubview(maleIcon)

Comment: @DavidWilliames No that didn't seem to work, it produced the same results. I believe something is wrong with my IndexPath.row because when i print it, the last row spits out "5" even though it the 12th row. But what i programmed i feel like is standard, I didnt do anything really that different.

Comment: @DavidWilliames The UIView is currently appearing, it just appears in multiple rows, sometimes reappears over itself.

Comment: Oh right. That's because you never remove it from the view/cell, so when the cell with the icon is being dequeued and reused, it will keep appearing for each instance that the cell was at one point at row 0. Does that make sense?

Comment: Another quick observation is that it looks like you are creating a table view with static cells based on the values in your 'items' array. Perhaps look at this repo https://github.com/venmo/Static it's really good for static table views. :)

Comment: haha hmm yea that kinda makes sense. Sorry if this bothers you, but would you mind answering the question with some code i should modify? It would help so much!! @DavidWilliames

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code for what should help you with your issues. I made a few assumptions about how you may be trying to implement. But this should be a great start for you.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/2ilyfnc1pqurjfd/AAC2rU-zlvUtjdKYV33JrQJQa?dl=0

I also highly recommend that you use auto layout for your various view dimensions rather than hard coding weird offsets. It may be difficult to start with. But it definitely pays off in the long run!

Comment: Hey David, I'm actually getting a small issue. The application crashes here:         "cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! CustomTableViewCell". And it says this : "Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' (0x10d214128) to 'UCSF_Lung_Nodules.CustomTableViewCell'". I believe its because I'm doing it programmatically and you did it using storyboard. Would you mind emailing or chatting with me? You've helped so much so far and i appreciate it but I need to get this done by Friday!!

Answer (score 0):

It's kinda strange that `maleIcon` is UIViewController property in your code.

Did you try to put in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

like that:

```
//Want to add UIView male Icon in first row
    if(indexPath.row == 0){
        let maleIcon = MaleIconView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 55, height: 55))
```

I'm not sure it will help with reusable cells though. What will help (but there is slightly more work) is to create your own cell class, add `maleIcon` as property, register this class with your table and put this in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` like that:

```
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    cell.maleIcon.hidden = false}
       else {
    cell.maleIcon.hidden = true}
```

Comment: @OriginalAlchemist After looking a bit more at your code, I think the best approach is to create your own cell class as mentioned here. If you plan on using a similar layout for each cell, i.e an icon for each, create your own IconTableViewCell class or something. Then instead of adding the maleIcon to the view, you could set the icon for your custom cell to be either Male, or another or none.

Comment: Yes, It was my plan from the start, but for some reason its not working.  I was thinking about creating a cell class, but thats not the issue.

The issue is that my indexPath is off.  I was printing out the number in my command line and it was off. The last row was indexPath number 5 even though its the 12th row. If i can fix this issue, all will be good!! But Im banging my head against the wall trying to figure out why its not!

I know this is troublesome but if you copy my code exactly over to a new project you can hopefully figure it out. Please! Im crying!! 

@DavidWilliames

Comment: The real issue is that the UIView appears twice, because the indexpath is off, and sometimes when i scroll down then back up, it appears again. But the UIView does appear in the correct cell. @DavidWilliames

Comment: @OriginalAlchemist I copied your code across in a new project. The reason why the indexPath is only printing up to 5 is because only 5 rows are visible on the screen at once. When you scroll down the other indexPaths should print. The way that UITableView's work is they recycle cells. So once the first cell go's off the screen, it will replace it down the bottom to scroll in as the new bottom one rather than initialise a new UITableViewCell. That is what the method `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` is doing. At the point of running, only 5 cells will initialise, because only 5 can be visible

Comment: @OriginalAlchemist Read the Apple docs on UITableViewCells to gain a better understanding of what I mean, and how they work. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7

Comment: Ah i see, you're a clever man @DavidWilliames . If i want a different UIView for each row, I will have to use "if(indexPath.row == 0)" and "if(indexPath.row == 1)" and so on correct? Now is that my problem? Because even if i create a custom UITableViewCell class, i will have to instantiate the class within the if statement, but i believe my issue is that the indexPath isnt exactly tied with the row because it changes when the user scrolls, thats why the same uiview is appearing on different rows.

Comment: No worries. @OriginalAlchemist If you have your custom UITableViewCell class keep track of if it should show a UIView and if so which one, then there will be a reference to a view for each cell, rather than one reference for the whole tableView. Then you can almost implement it the same as you have done. If you need I can write out a code example for you.

Comment: @DavidWilliames example code will help so much please : ... )